# Subdomain URL Masking

Tags: php, .htaccess, masking

I have a wordpress site with an admin panel and I want to show the admin panel to public but within a subdomain. I do not want to show the url structure, however.

What I want is : subdomain.domain.com to mask another URL and all it's pages.
Basically I want to open the admin panel of a wordpress site masked in a sub-domain. So users would open sub.x.com and would see domain.com/wp-admin and be able to login or do whatever. I want it to work just like an iframe but using subdomaain masking. I don't want to show users the url structure or anything. Please give me the best way-out possible.

Comment: So you can do this initially, yet WP uses redirects to handle logins and post login actions. So this may only work properly to direct users to the Admin login initially. Once there, they will be redirected to other sections. If that's ok, I can provide some .htaccess URL Rules you can look at.

Comment: i do  understand, but are those url redirections done with url on browser? How does the iframe work then? I want something very similar to iframe but not within a screen frame.

Comment: URL Rewrites that WordPress uses are done on the server side. I never mentioned an iframe. I do not understand your questions.